# Mail not sending on Server 2008 using NAT between 2 NIC's

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, nat, email

I recently moved from a svr2003 domain to a new 2008 domain. The setup I had below allowed internet and also smtp configured in outlook to go via 192.168.1.1

nic 1 192.168.1 - wan
sn 255.255.255.0

nic 2 192.168.2 - Lan
sn 255.255.0.0

Now on 2008 internet access is fine with nat setup as above. However mail no longer goes out.
DNS and DHCP have been setup as well and are working normally. I have noticed a few differences in options between 2003 and 2008 server in RRAS, with 2003 having more configurability.

Please help

Regards
Brad

Answer (score 0):

First test would be to try a telnet session to another known Internet SMTP host on port 25. You might also look through the firewall settings to ensure port 25 is not somehow blocked.